# Basic Python metaprogramming: populating dictionaries?

Tags: python, exception, dictionary, metaprogramming, conditional-statements

I've been learning meta-programming in Ruby, and have found it quite useful. I'm sure I can do the same in Python.

E.g.: how would I rewrite this function given this function in a concise and general way using meta-programming?

```
def foo(bar=None, baz=None, qux=None, haz=None):
    txt = {}

    if bar:
        txt.update({'bar': bar})
    if baz:
        txt.update({'baz': baz})
    if qux:
        txt.update({'qux': qux})
    if haz:
        txt.update({'haz': haz})

    return txt
```

(this is obviously over-simplified, in practice one might perform different tasks based on value-set of individual keys)

Comment: Unless I am missing something obvious, I don't think this question has anything to do with Python meta programming?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `**kwargs` syntax:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    txt = {}
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        if v:
            txt[k] = v
    return txt
```

Or, if you're short on ink:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    return dict(((k,v) for k, v in kwargs.items() if v))
```

*As suggested by Clement Bellot:*

If you want to be sure those args are in your expected set, you could have an `ALLOWED_PARAMS = ('bar','baz','qux','haz')` constant and replace `if v` with `if v and k in ALLOWED_PARAMS`.

*As suggested by DSM:*

If you're running Python 2.7+, you can use a [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).
This version also offers an alternate take on the "Allowed variables" problem:

```
def foo(bar=None, baz=None, qux=None, haz=None): 
    return {k:v for k,v in locals().items() if v}
```

---

Let's say you actually wanted to call functions depending on those parameters being there, you could do:

```
KWARGS_TO_FUNCTIONS = {
    'bar':fn_bar,
    'baz':fn_baz, 
    'qux':fn_qux,
    'haz':fn_haz,
}

def foo(**kwargs):
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        if v:
            try:
                KWARGS_TO_FUNCTIONS[k](v)
            except KeyError:
                pass # We didn't want that kwarg.
```

---

Now, all in all, I'm not totally sure that's really 'meta'.

Comment: Could add a test for `k in {'bar','baz','qux','haz'}`.

Comment: @ClementBellot Well, I'm not sure that's what's expected in the question, but I'll add it, yes

Comment: `def foo(bar=None, baz=None, qux=None, haz=None): return {k:v for k,v in locals().items() if v}` would work too.  I kind of think the OP's code has a bug and `if bar is not None` was meant, though, otherwise `foo(bar=0)` wouldn't load the dict.  But without more information on what the OP is actually trying to do, it's hard to see how metaprogramming would be useful.

Comment: @DSM I added the dict comprehension to the answer. I suggest you add the `is not None` pitfall as a comment to their question! : )

Answer (score 3):

Thomas has given a few implementations using `**kwargs`.
I don't think you need the `if`s when using `**kwargs`.  In the original code, they are necessary to test whether the parameter was omitted or not.  When using `**kwargs`, the dictionary will contain exactly the given parameters, so all we need is

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    return kwargs
```

This implementation is not even needed – you can use the `dict()` constructor instead:

```
>>> dict(bar=1, baz=2, qux=3, haz=4)
{'qux': 3, 'haz': 4, 'baz': 2, 'bar': 1}
```